# php ajax , SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

したいことは：送信ボタンを押すとincludes/sync.phpのファイルが実行したいです。

説明：
mysqlデータベースからphpでデータを取得して最新のid順で表示しています、それぞれのidにボタンを設置してデータを送信してphpファイルを実行していますが
下記のエラー出ていますが何が間違っていますでしょうか？
id(1)からid(10)まで、ありますが最新のid(10)を押すと下記のエラーが出ますがその他のidのボタンを押しても反応が何もしないです！！
なぜでしょうか？誰かがご教授お願いします。

説明補足：/* 下記の質問は、これをajaxで書き換えた場合のエラーです
これは正しく動作しますが=> echo "送信";*/

下記のエラー：

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

１、下記の送信ボタンを上記のエラーが出ます

```
echo "<td><a rel='$test_id' href='javascript:void(0)' id='sw'>送信</a></td>";

<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://ajax.googleapi.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#sw").click(function(){
            var param = {"test_id" : "{$test_id}"};
                $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url : "includes/sync.php",
                data: JSON.stringify(param),
                dataType : "text",
            }).done(function(data){
                alert(data.text);
            }).fail(function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert(errorThrown);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: url : "includes/sync.php",のパスをurl : "./includes/sync.php",に直したら下記のエラーが出ました。
undefined

Comment: これ、全文じゃないですよね？、`SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`とはJavascriptの構文エラーになります。要するに、カッコやクォーテーションの開始・終了があっていないとかそんなエラーです。PHPの出力をJavascriptで使っているのでPHPの出力がおかしいと思うんです。

Comment: 全分ではないです。
phpファイルは問題なく動作していますね

Comment: これはPHPの構文エラーではないですよね？PHPの出力は成功していても、その値がJavaScriptの構文をぶった切っていて受け取れていないのです。（たとえば`"`でくくっているのにその間の文字列に`"`を出力したり）。だからJavaScriptでエラーが出ていると思っています。

Comment: 確かに、しっかり確認してまた、報告します

Answer (score 1):

jQueryのリンクが間違っているようです。`http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js`に直してみてください。(googleapi -> googleapis)

Comment: ありがとうございます。
質問投稿の時にsを抜けてしました。
ご指摘の通りに直してみたけど、同じエラーでした。

Comment: $test_idを定義しているところ見せてもらえますか？
ついでに、他のボタンが反応しない原因ですが、すべてのボタンに同じID(#sw)を使っているからだと思います。`id='sw$test_id'`や`$("#sw$test_id")`のようなIDで直せます。

Comment: @cthorme さん
下記が$test_idの定義です

include "db.php";
if (!isset($_GET['test_id'])) {
    echo '{$test_id} can not found the param';
    return;
}
$test_id = $_GET['test_id'];

$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "test");
if ($db->connect_error) {
    echo 'database connect failed.';
    return;
}